# Creating a queue of invites for iOS app for non users?

Tags: ios

I have a client that wants wants me to build in a sharing feature.  This is the use case:

- User invites a non-user to download the app and at the same time share a private profile.
- When user submits the invitation, the system creates a temporary account ID with a status 0 in the database.
- The invited user gets an email from the system with a link to download the app and is given an activation key and instruction on how to activate the account..
- Once the user enters email address, first name, last name and activation key, they will be prompted to fill out the password field to create a new password.
- Once these steps are made, the user then can view invitations

Essentially this creates an account for a user without them explicitly doing so. What is your take on this? Is this outside Apple guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

No one will be able to tell you with certainty what's acceptable, but if you review Apple's guidelines, you'll see that requiring a user to enter personal information (email and name in your case) for the app to function is not permitted.

You might be able to get away with it by having the account creation all occur on the web. (i.e. if everything in your steps after the first one occurs on the web) and then simply allow the user to log in to their already-created account in the app. (So, it would be similar to Facebook where you simply require the user to have an account before they can use the app at all, rather than forcing them to make an account and provide personal details to do so.)